# Get requests in one session using R

Tags: r, translate

I need to send requests from one session, this is an example made on `python` but i need to translate into `R` language.

```
import requests
import lxml.html
import BeautifulSoup

login = '---'
password = '---'
url = 'http://hh.ru/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'DNT': '1'
}
session = requests.session()
data = session.get(url, headers=headers).content

page = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
form = page.forms[3]
form.fields['username'] = login
form.fields['password'] = password

response = session.post(form.action, data=form.form_values())
link= "http://hh.ru/search/resume?area=1&clusters=true&text=xxx&pos=full_text&logic=normal&exp_period=all_time"
data2 = session.get(link, headers=headers).text
```

Comment: Can you pinpoint which part of the code should go to through different R sessions?

Comment: from R i need send headers and something else that I do not know. when i try send only headers i have 40x  status

Comment: Perhaps you could invest some time in learning web scraping capabilities in R. You can start here: http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

Comment: I am guided in web scraping. When i send request from r, using httr or RCurl, i always have 40x status